# org-link to the exact page-position in a pdf file

Tags: org-mode, pdf, org-link, pdf-tools

*Newest EDIT*

I think my question wasn't very clear, so I'm trying to put some details.

1. With `pdf-tools` opening pdf files withing Emacs (`PDFview`
   buffers) works great. What I like is to get an org-link to a
   precise position (of the pointer on a page): Just a link that I can
   copy and paste into any org-file to use is it later  to go directly (without activating org-noter)
   to that position.

   ("precise position": I'd like to get the x- and y-values of the
   pointer. But the y-value alone (scroll position) is ok.)
2. The PDF file shouldn't be changed. Neither at producing the link
   nor at a later opening of the link (from an org file).

   I just need a temporary icon at the position, like the arrow in
   `org-noter` which you get with `org-noter-sync-current-note`.

   Unfortunately this function only works in an "`org-noter` buffer"
   and I need a "globally" valid link.

---

I often use in org-files pdf-links like this:
`[[pdf:~/book.pdf::5++2.13]]`
After clicking I get the pdf file buffer on the right page: 5.
And `PDFview` seems to go to the right exact position at that page: I can see in status bar: 10% an when I change the y-value from 2.13 to 10.13 (5++10.13),  I see 'Bot'(Bottom) there.

My problem is that I don't get any pointer/icon at that specific position.
Any idea to solve it? Should I change some variables?

I've installed `org-pdftools` as described:
https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools

Note: I don't have at that position a real annotation in the pdf file. So it's maybe not the default use of the link function.

---

EDIT: I've deleted my old code here, it was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

SECOND EDIT (incl. 'main' answer)

As mentioned in the comments, this feature has already been implemented into `org-pdftools`. However, `org-pdftools` does insert a *permanent* text annotation, but I guess that is not too much of a problem for you.

To get it to work (currently, until https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools/pull/75 gets merged), just replace the `org-pdftools-use-freestyle-annot` with `org-pdftools-use-freepointer-annot` in the installation code as given in the org-pdftools [README](https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools#installation). Afterwards you can insert the pointer/text annotation using `M-x org-noter-pdftools-insert-precise-note`. The pointer is customizable also. Just do `M-x customize-variable` and type `org pointer` to find the relevant variables.

And just to come back to the translation of the y-position, you could translate it as follows, but it is probably not what you desire as it only represents the scrolling position:

```lisp
 (defun my-pointer-function (orig-func &rest args)
  (apply orig-func args)
  (let ((height (round
                 (/
                  (*
                   (string-to-number (match-string 4 (car args)))
                   (cdr (pdf-view-image-size)))
                  (frame-char-height)))))
    (pdf-annot-add-text-annotation (cons 10 height) "Circle")))
```

(THIRD EDIT)

You could delete these pointers again for example when you are changing the page using e.g.:

```lisp
(defvar my-pointers nil)

(add-hook 'pdf-view-before-change-page-hook #'pdf-pointer-delete-hook-function)

(defun pdf-pointer-delete-hook-function ()
  (while my-pointers
    (pdf-annot-delete (pop my-pointers))))
```

I am not sure about the robustness of this code, but you can modify/improve it whenever it seems not to work.

FIRST EDIT

It looks like, if you do not have `pdf-tools` installed (i.e. the feature available), then you can use `org-pdftools-open-custom-open` to define a custom function for opening the link.

However, this feature appears not to be available when you have pdf-tools installed. So then you could advise the function `org-pdftools-open-pdftools`, e.g. as follows:

```lisp
(defun my-pointer-function (orig-func &rest args)
  (apply orig-func args)
  (pdf-annot-add-text-annotation '(100 . 200) "Circle")
  (print args))

(advice-add 'org-pdftools-open-pdftools :around #'my-pointer-function)
```

This advice (i.e. the `my-pointer-function`) will also print the args. I'll leave it to you to translate the args to some actual position where you would like to have the pointer inserted.

END EDIT

I guess there is no straightforward/default way to achieve this, because it is not possible to draw on .png images in Emacs.

If you still want it, then there are multiple hacks possible, of which probably the easiest option is to draw an icon (text annotation) with `pdf-annot-add-text-annotation`, e.g.:
`(pdf-annot-add-text-annotation '(100 . 200) "Circle")`.

To preview (or just for fun) the possible icons (in `pdf-annot-standard-text-icons`), you can evaluate the following lines in a pdf buffer:

```
(let ((pos 0))
  (dolist (type pdf-annot-standard-text-icons)
    (pdf-annot-add-text-annotation (cons pos 0) type)
    (setq pos (+ pos 100))))
```

These annotations will only get saved if you save the document. Or you could additionally add another hack to delete it again when you start scrolling, which should not be too difficult if you know some emacs-lisp.

Comment: I have pdf-tools installed: https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. So then, as I wrote, this answer (using the advice) should work for you. Also, I am not sure how you installed `pdf-tools` but you would probably prefer to use the maintained fork at https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools

Comment: I installed it with the internal function of emacs (`list-packages`) from melpa, and your link is the true one. 
Thanks for your help. It worked, also with the "translation" of the args. I've added the code to my answer. I hope it's ok.

Comment: "Or you could additionally add another hack to delete it again when you start scrolling, which should not be too difficult if you know some emacs-lisp."
I think this is too difficult for me.

Comment: Okay, I probably finished this answer too quickly. Your solution does not seem right to me, as I don't think the number in the link represents the x and y position. You can find how to translate the `y` position from the body of the `org-pdftools-open-pdftools`, but it only represent the scrolling `y` position. However, it turns out to be unnecessary because the feature turns out to have been implemented already in `org-(noter-)pdftools` (but currently it is inaccurately documented). I will add another edit to my answer.

Comment: Oh you're right, the position is different from the one I get in an `org-noter` session. Thanks.

Comment: I have created a [PR](https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools/pull/75) that corrects the documentation.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with you new function (EDIT2) `my-pointer-function`. I get an error message: "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil"
-
"However, org-pdftools does insert a permanent text annotation, but I guess that is not too much of a problem for you." Well, I have to avoid saving the changes every time. But it's ok.

Comment: My friend tested it and it is working fine there also. So I am not sure how you copied the code. Anyway, stack-exchange warns here to avoid long discussions in the comment section, and it tells me we should be able to move to some chat somehow. Or otherwise you could visit the Spacemacs chat also, and I can help you debugging over there. But again, note that this only represents the y-scrolling position (vscroll). If you want to get a pointer at some exact location then you should use the feature that comes with `org-(noter-)pdftools`.